# How do I receive Oanda stream using oanda API?

Tags: stream, trading

I'd like to receive trading information using Oanda-v20-API. On the site it says that I can use rest-api to get a stream, but I can't find out how to do it using their liibrary?

Or using jax-rs?

Thanks.

Comment: There are several libraries you can use to access their V20-API. Getting a stream is supported with that.  Check https://github.com/oanda. For python you can also use oandapyV20 : https://github.com/hootnot/oanda-api-v20

Answer (score 0):

try this in python 3 or put it into a jupyter notebook

```
import requests
import json

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           "Authorization": "Bearer <<YOUR ACCESS CODE HERE>>"}
# Streaming prices
baseurl = 'https://stream-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/<<your account id here>>/pricing/stream'
payload = { 'instruments' : 'EUR_USD'}

r = requests.get(baseurl, params=payload, headers=headers, stream=True)
print(r.headers)
print('\n')

for line in r.iter_lines():
    if line:
        print(json.loads(line.decode("utf-8")))
```